# Excel Question: I need a date and time formula to convert between time zones

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I am trying to find a way to calculate a duration in days between my, time zone (Central), and (Pacific; Mountain; Eastern). Just do not know where to start. My criteria would be as follows:

Cell C5:C100 would be the timestamps in this format:3/18/2010 23:45 but for different dates and times. 
Cell D5:D100 would be the corresponding timezone in text form: Pacific; Mountain; Eastern; Central.

Cell F5 would be where the duration in days would need to be.

Just not sure how to write the formula to give me what I am looking for. I appreciate any assistance in advance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [Time Zones And Daylight Savings Time](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx)

> Neither VBA nor VB6 provides any
>   native functions for working with Time
>   Zones, Greenwich Mean Time (GMT, also
>   called UTC), or Daylight Savings Time.
>   To work with these values, you must
>   use some Windows Application
>   Programmatic Interface (API)
>   functions. This page describes these
>   API functions and how to use them in
>   your VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably a nested IF formula:

`=IF(D22="Pacific",(1/24*2),IF(D22="Mountain",(1/24),IF(D22="Eastern",-(1/24),0)))`

Or using the `LOOKUP` function to return the same:

`=(C5+(1/24*LOOKUP(D5,{"Central","Eastern","Mountain","Pacific"},{-2,-3,-1,0})))-C5`

Alternatively, you could create a UDF that takes the local date/time and works out the Pacific date/time from the textual representation of the timezone:

```
Function TimeDifference(LocalTime As Range, TimeZone As Range) As Date
    Application.Volatile
    Dim TimeOffset As Long

    Select Case TimeZone
        Case "Mountain"
            TimeOffset = -1
        Case "Central"
            TimeOffset = -2
        Case "Eastern"
            TimeOffset = -3
        Case Else
            TimeOffset = 0
    End Select
    TimeDifference = (1 / 24 * TimeOffset)
End Function
```

You would call this from column F like this:

`=TIMEDIFFERENCE(C5,D5)`